# os.path.join seems sensitive to opening slash, why?

Tags: python, os.path, expanduser

Adding a slash to Documents in os.join produces different results when I think it should not.  Why?

Just trying to write code that does reasonable things for multiple users.

```
import os
# Initialize output files and folders, following principle of separating code from data
homeDir = os.path.expanduser('~')
targetDir = os.path.join(homeDir, '/Documents/Jeopardy/output')
print(targetDir)
# produces /Documents/Jeopardy/output  which is not expected
targetDir = os.path.join(homeDir, 'Documents/Jeopardy/output')
print(targetDir)
# produces /home/max/Documents/Jeopardy/output  which is expected
```

I expected both joins to produce 
      /home/max/Documents/Jeopardy/output
But the first one didn't.  I must not understand the join doc, but I can't see why I get different outputs.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`join()` docstring](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

> If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component.

`'/Documents/Jeopardy/output'` is an absolute path, so the first part is discarded.

Behaviorally, using the relative rather than absolute path arguably makes more sense; it doesn't make a ton of sense to prepend anything to an absolute path, since it already starts at the FS root.

Comment: Thanks, the light dawns.  I had read the doc before I posted, and still didn't get it.  After reading your answer I used isabs('path') to play around and think I understand now.  Starting with the path separator, in my case '/', refers to the root, which contains on Ubunto folders bin and home, among others.  Starting without it refers to the current working directory.    Many thanks.